# Achille Mbembe's critique of desire in postcolony

Tags: political-philosophy

> In the postcolony, wherein a particular form of power rages, wherein
> the dominant and the subjugated are specifically linked in one and the
> same bundle of desire, enthusiasm for the end is often expressed in
> the language of the religious. One reason why is that the postcolony
> is a relatively specific form of capture and emasculation of the
> desire for revolt and the will to struggle. Society’s energies are
> reinvested not necessarily in work, profit-seeking, or the
> recapitulation of the world and its renewal, but in a sort of
> unmediated, immediate enjoyment, which is simultaneously empty of
> enjoyment and a libidinal sort of predation—all things that explain
> both the absence of revolutionary transformation and the established
> regimes’ lack of hegemony.

How is this citation from Achille Mbembe's *Necropolitics* (pp. 29-30) related to Deleuze's analysis of desiring-machines in his Anti-Oedipus?

Comment: Thos sounds very specific, almost like a typical essay question in a related seminar would. Could you provide some background to tell us how you arrived at that question and what your ideas and attempts on answering it are?

Comment: As I have just become interested in both Deleuze's Anti-Oedipus—and I am reading Mbembe's work, I cannot as yet provide a cogent account. The question is just my first endeavour to draw the contours of what may turn into a picture in no less than six months studying— if I can devote my time and energy to it. Overall, my purpose in asking the question was to see whether these works are related to any extent. I am sorry that I was not competent enough to appropriately answer your question.

Comment: No worries, I did not want to criticise the gist of the question. It just helps people who want to answer when you can specify a bit the context and direction of your question, so that answers can be suited to your needs and not end up overly general.